# Select2 with multiple selected values not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using `select2.min.js version 3.5.2`

I am trying to select a few values by default.

Here is my HTML:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="params.parameterRealValue" class="multiValueNoTypeInParameter multiValueParameter select2Control" id="parameterRealValue1" 
                th:classappend="${parameter.hasChildren ? ' cascadingParameterValue' : ''}"
                th:remove="body">
    <option></option>
    <option value="Value 1">Value 1</option>
</select>
```

Here is my JS code:

```
var multiValueNoType = $("select.multiValueNoTypeInParameter#parameterRealValue" + i);

if(multiValueNoType.length > 0) {
    multiValueNoType.html(options).select2();
    var multipleVals = (defaultValue.v).split(",");
    //defaultValue.v has comma seperated values of state codes
    var simpleArr = [];
    for(var multiCounter=0; multiCounter < multipleVals.length; multiCounter++) {
        // simpleArr.push(multipleVals[multiCounter]);
        simpleArr.push({id: multipleVals[multiCounter], text: multipleVals[multiCounter]});
    }

    multiValueNoType.select2().select2("val", simpleArr );
}
```

Everything works fine if the selected or retrieved is a single value (only one option). The whole issue is for multiple values.

The problem is the javascript is successfully placing the values to the text field but the selected values are not removed from the drop down.

And, when I submit the form, old values if any are not submitted but the new ones are submitted correctly. I have attached a image for multiple values.

[image: when multiple values are retrieved]

I have tried hard to find a correct solution but nothing worked. Any help in this regards will greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you trying to do?
The value object is an array of objects (it needs to have the attributes 'id' and 'text'... What's the 'multipleVals' format?

Comment: @Eldius I have even tried doing that but it is not working. Edited the code

Comment: Did you tried to use just $("#parameterRealValue1") to get the component? This way you'll get the "Select2 object", not just the HTML component...

Comment: @Eldius That doesn't populate any values (I mean pre-populating)